# PHP - Get file extension (image) without knowing it

Tags: php, filenames, glob

How can I get the extension of an image file without knowing what it is? I have tried using glob, as below, but it returns an error: **"Array Notice: Undefined offset: 0"**

```
$path=BASEURL."content/images/profile_images/".$imageName;
$results= glob($path.'.*');

$filename = $results[0];
echo $filename;
```

Comment: There is a built in function `pathinfo` check answer will be easier to maintain too.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `$imageName` can be?

Comment: FYI, "Array Notice: Undefined offset: 0" means that index 0 exceeds the bounds of the array. Since 0 is the first index of an array, the array has a length of 0.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am saying ... if you use the function then you will get the extension or an empty string if your file does not have an extension. Am i making sense guys ?

Comment: @woofmeow Your answer will only ever returns an empty string because gray has stated that the extension is not in the $imageName variable. If he had the full filename then he could use pathinfo() to retrieve the extension, however he DOESN'T have the full file name. He only has the basename minus the extension. His path is essentially "content/images/profile_image/myimg" and NEVER "content/images/profile_image/myimg.ext", therefore if you pass the former string into the pathinfo function, you will ONLY ever get an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Your glob is bad and it's returning an empty array, hence the error. It's not a regular expression, it's a shell expansion and `*` is a wildcard. Currently it will try to match any filename that begins with a `.`. ie. `.htaccess`.

If you want it to match any file use: `glob($path.'*')`

If you want it to match any file with a period in it: `glob($path.'*.*')`

Answer (score 1):

Use PHPs built in function `pathinfo` like this

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

For example

```
echo pathinfo("http://www.google.com//swf/fvere.ext",PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//Output : ext
```

Read the [manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: OP doesn`t have the full file path from the looks of the code he already provided.

Comment: He does have it isn't it here `$path=BASEURL."content/images/profile_images/".$imageName;` ?

Comment: thanks I have the entire path and image name...but I can't get the file extension, which I don't have

Comment: I would recommend using a built in function @gray as opposed to the other method. Will be easier to check in future. If it helped feel free to accept and upvote ;-). Cheers .

Comment: thank you for the tip, but I have tried and this does not give me the extension

Comment: It is a built in function @gray it has to work. Check examples from the documentation link i have provided. Do you want me to update it with an example ?

Comment: I tried $path=BASEURL . "content/images/profile_images/".$image;
  $filename = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   echo $filename;  ----and it gave nothing back?

Comment: Since OP appended a wildcard to `$imageName`, I assumed `$imageName` was the actual name of the file minus the extension e.g. myimg instead of myimg.ext. Otherwise the OP misunderstands the purpose of the `glob` function.

Comment: yes @noahnu you are correct. $imageName can be for example, "monkey"

Comment: Maybe your baseurl is not set to some value. Check example above and try it @gray . It works for me. Copy it and see.

Comment: my baseurl startes with "http: //mysite.com/", is this correct?

Comment: Yes that should work too .. I have edited to include a url ... check that .. it should work @gray .

Comment: @woofmeow, gray doesn't have the extension in the $imageName. gray, don't use `http://mysite.com/`, use an absolute or relative path from your webroot. If your PHP script is on the same server as the image, you don't use your site's domain name.

Comment: @noahnu , gray in that case the function will return an empty string. I have given the doc link too.

Comment: yes I don't want an empty string, I want the filename + the extension...thanks for trying though

Comment: You can use `PATHINFO_DIRNAME | PATHINFO_BASENAME | PATHINFO_EXTENSION | PATHINFO_FILENAME` either of these depending on the need.And concatenateor Maybe I am  not just getting it. Perhaps i need a break lol

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but it is not the best way:

```
$path="content/images/profile_images/".$image; 

$file = $path.".";

$ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "JPEG", "gif", "png", "bmp");
for($x = 0; $x < 6; $x++)
{
    $image = $file.$ext[$x];
    if(file_exists($image))
    {
        $pic=$image;
        echo $pic;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you posted as an answer, this will work:

```
$dir = "content/images/profile_images/";
$results = glob("{$dir}{$imageName}.*");

if(count($results)>0){
   echo pathinfo($results[0], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

It appears that your error was an invalid file path. The image was not at that path which contained the `BASEURL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can "explode" the end of the filename to get the extension.

```
$file = 'image.jpg';
$temp = explode(".", $file);
$extension = end($temp);
echo $extension;
```

Will output "jpg"